# N channel MOSFET as power on switch

Tags: mosfet, low-power

I want to use a small slide switch to turn my circuit on and off so that the circuit draws no/very little power when off. The circuit will only draw a maximum of approx. 500mA @ 5V when on, but to my surprise the switch I want to use is not rated to this. So I decided to use an N-channel MOSFET to switch my circuit on and off. Part number for the MOSFET is DMN3404L-7. A bit overkill, I know.
[image: N-channel MOSFET as a power switch]

Header P1 is the power supply header for the entire circuit.

I am wondering if this is a proper implementation of an N-channel MOSFET. In particular, is there a good reason why I should not connect the drain port to common ground as shown? Also would a P-channel MOSFET on the high side be better suited for this?

Comment: Is this entire setup for that single LED, or is there more of the circuit you haven't shown?

Comment: Also, it seems you're using the symbol for a thermistor instead of a fuse.

Comment: @Reinderien There is more of the circuit that is not shown. It figured it wasn't relevant so I didn't include it. F1 is a PTC (resettable fuse). Maybe I got the designator (or symbol) wrong :S

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: why not just use a better switch?

Comment: @Reinderien. It will not be small enough for my purpose. I searched around digikey for quite a while:)

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/cw-industries/GF-123-3011/CWI334-ND/4089772 3A 125V, 5mm slide switch

Comment: @Reinderien It is still larger than what I would prefer, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What are your dimensional constraints?

Comment: The type of switch should be a 3mm pin pitch or less, no wider than 11mm, standoff height 6mm or less. And right angle connector

Comment: Depending on your load and what it might need to interface with and how your power supply 0 volts might interact with other circuits a P type MOSFET may be the only sensible route.

Comment: Q1 looks backwards.  Source should face ground.  I would definitely look into using a P type instead and switch VCC though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that should work just fine. However you need to be careful with the other side of your circuit because if it becomes grounded it will bypass the N-Channel MOSFET. This is why a P-Channel switching the VCC is usually preferred.

Comment: The reason why I'm using N Channel is because the same component is used in other parts of my circuit, and I want to keep the unique part numbers low.